# Python semiprime factorization equation solver issues

Tags: python, equation-solving, prime-factoring

I am a farmer / novice number theory researcher. I happened to discover some years back a pattern that emerged in the distribution of the prime numbers that related the number of primes to the operation of 300 Fibonacci-like sequences. Well, as a person who has always used pen and paper I was at a loss when it came to converting my methods into computer code (so I hired a programmer to implement my code in Perl). That code worked but it was not the process that I now need; I wish to ask a community of programmers what they think is the best approach to making this (Python) code work. Also, as a researcher I am not overly concerned with people appropriating this code for their own uses - I would just like to see what you do with it!

The results generated by the Perl program were published in the AT&T Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. https://oeis.org/search?q=helkenberg&language=english&go=Search

The program below is my recent effort but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get certain parts of the code to work.

For instance (from the larger program below),

```
print"""THIS CODE WILL NOT COMPILE (example p*q = 29*73)
print [(int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0)]/90 #example 23
print [(int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1)]/90 #example 215

z(0) = [(int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0)]/90
z(1) = [(int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1)]/90
#This defines a new process, a Fibonacci-like sequence:

a = z(1) - z(0) #example (192=215-23)
g = 180 #think the unit circle, clock cycles

m_0 = a + g #example 192+180 = 372

z(2) = m_0 + z(1) #example 587 = 372 + 215

m_1 = m_0 + g #example 552 = 372 + 180

z(3) = z(2)+ m_1 #example 1139 = 587 + 552

m_2 = m_1 + g #example 732 = 552 + 180

z(4) = z(3) + m_2 #example 1871 = 1139 + 732
```

I am teaching myself how to code and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement this!!!

Lastly, I need to use those values (of the z term) to solve an equation of the form:

```
0 = r - [(((90*n))+29)*y) + z_n]
0 = r - [(((90*n))+73)*y) + z_n]
```

where the z term is used for both 29 and 73 (as an example)

Here is what I have so far.

```
print    "1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139"

variable = raw_input('copy and paste the above number')

#This valuable function reduces an arbitrarily large number to the SUM OF ITS DIGITS
new_variable = sum(map(int, str(variable)))
print new_variable

next_step = sum(map(int, str(new_variable)))
print next_step

new_step = sum(map(int, str(next_step)))

print "The digital root of our test number is", new_step, "A fine answer."

if int(new_step) > 9:
print "We cannot have a two digit digital root!Enter the sum of those two numbers here!"

newest_data = raw_input ('>enter the digital root here')

#newest_data = raw_input ()

if new_step == 3:
print "This number is divisible by 3."
if new_step == 6:
print "This number is divisible by 3."
if new_step == 9:
print "This number is divisible by 3 and 9."

if newest_data == 3:
print "This number is divisible by 3."
if newest_data == 6:
print "This number is divisible by 3."
if newest_data == 9:
print "This number is divisible by 3 and 9."

print "What is the last digit of our number?"
last_digit = raw_input("Last digit here")

print last_digit

if int(last_digit) == 0:
print "This number is divisible by 2 and 5."
if int(last_digit) == 2:
print "This number is divisible by 2."
if int(last_digit) == 4:
print "This number is divisible by 2."
if int(last_digit) == 6:
print "This number is divisible by 2."
if int(last_digit) == 8:
print "This number is divisible by 2."

digital_root = int(new_step)
new_digit = int(last_digit)

if digital_root == 1 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 91"

elif digital_root == 1 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 73"

elif digital_root == 1 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 37"

elif digital_root == 1 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 19"

elif digital_root == 2 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 11"

elif digital_root == 2 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 73"

elif digital_root == 2 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 47"

elif digital_root == 2 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 29"

elif digital_root == 4 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 31"

elif digital_root == 4 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 13"

elif digital_root == 4 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 67"

elif digital_root == 4 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 49"

elif digital_root == 5 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 41"

elif digital_root == 5 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 23"

elif digital_root == 5 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 77"

elif digital_root == 5 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 59"

elif digital_root == 7 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 61"

elif digital_root == 7 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 43"

elif digital_root == 7 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 7"

elif digital_root == 7 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 79"

elif digital_root == 8 and new_digit == 1:
print "your primitive is 71"

elif digital_root == 8 and new_digit == 3:
print "your primitive is 53"

elif digital_root == 8 and new_digit == 7:
print "your primitive is 17"

elif digital_root == 8 and new_digit == 9:
print "your primitive is 89"


primitive = raw_input("enter primitive here")
new_value = int(variable) - int(primitive)
stored_data = new_value/90

print "this is our new number, the position of our test number in a dr,ld index.", stored_data

print "This number above is our test number (r)."

tuple = [73,91,19,37,11,23,29,77,47,59,83,41,13,61,31,43,49,7, 67,79,17,89,53,71]

print tuple
print " the example is based on 29*73"
p = raw_input("p from tuple (to be defined)") # example 29
q = raw_input("q associated with p") #example 73

#def make_incrementor (n): return lambda x: x + n
#cannot figure this one out
#notice x_0 and then x_1:
print"""THIS CODE WILL NOT COMPILE (example p*q = 29*73)
print [(int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0)]/90 #example 23
print [(int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1)]/90 #example 215

z(0) = [(int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0)]/90
z(1) = [(int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1)]/90

#This defines a new process, a Fibonacci-like sequence:

a = z(1) - z(0) #example (192=215-23)
g = 180 #think the unit circle, clock cycles

m_0 = a + g #example 192+180 = 372

z(2) = m_0 + z(1) #example 587 = 372 + 215

m_1 = m_0 + g #example 552 = 372 + 180

z(3) = z(2)+ m_1 #example 1139 = 587 + 552

m_2 = m_1 + g #example 732 = 552 + 180

z(4) = z(3) + m_2 #example 1871 = 1139 + 732

"""

print "seed values for sequence z = [23, 215]"
print "set of z terms [23, 215, 587, 1139, 1871,.....] "


print "notice the last-digit pattern for the z term means that every term of z will end  in a [3, 5, 7, 9, 1], in that order, but also IN A POWER SERIES. Also notice that our test number (r) ends with the last digit 8. So prior to computing w, we know that none of the solutions represented by z (where z = r) are possible."

print """
there are 24 equations (posed as alternatives):

r = stored_data test number, RSA-100 clock position
print "RSA-100 = 19 +     (90*16917833643583704005951315312584860330200756832904229873976761050890255147321698862822226118800068)"
Startng at 19 degrees, RSA100 is 169..... 1/4 rotations from the 0 position on the clock face.

#special case: where r-z = 0, factor found.

0 = r - [(((90*n))+19)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-19)]/x - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+91)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-91)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+37)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((n-z_n)/y)-37)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+73)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-73)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+11)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-11)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+59)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-59)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+29)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-29)]/x - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+41)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-41)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+47)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-47)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+77)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-77)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+83)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-83)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+23)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-83)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+13)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-13)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+43)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-43)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+31)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-31)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+79)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-79)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+49)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-49)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+61)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-61)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+67)*y) + z_n
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-67)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+7)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-7)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+17)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-17)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+53)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-53)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+71)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-71)]/n - 90]

0 = r - [(((90*n)+89)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-89)]/n - 90]
"""



#Here is the OLD PROGRAM in Perl

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigInt;
use POSIX;
use Getopt::Long;

my $rsa              = '';
my $p                = '';
my $q                = '';
my $digit_root_chart = '';

GetOptions(
'rsa|r=s'   => \$rsa,
'p=s'       => \$p,
'q=s'       => \$q,
'digit|d=i' => \$digit_root_chart,
) or die "Problem with command";

# /*
#  * General algorithm goes here.
#  *
#  */

my $length_of_semiprime = length($rsa);
my $digit_root          = &digit_root($rsa);

print "digit root: $digit_root\n";

$rsa = Math::BigInt->new($rsa);
print "rsa: $rsa\n";
my $new_rsa = $rsa->copy();
$new_rsa -=
  $digit_root_chart;  # need to figure out a way to tablize the digit root table
$new_rsa /= 90;
print "new_rsa: $new_rsa\n";

$p = Math::BigInt->new($p);
$q = Math::BigInt->new($q);
my $y = &first_two_calcs( $p, $q );
print "p = $p, q = $q\n";
&check_for_factor( $p, $q, $y );

$p += 90;
$q += 90;
my $z = &first_two_calcs( $p, $q );
print "p = $p, q = $q\n";
&check_for_factor( $p, $q, $z );

$p += 90;
$q += 90;
print "p = $p, q = $q\n";
my @r = &second_calcs( $y, $z );
$y = $r[0];
$z = $r[1];
&check_for_factor( $p, $q, $z );

while (1) {
   $p += 90;
   $q += 90;

my @t = &third_calc( $y, $z );
$y = $t[0];
$z = $t[1];

if ( $z <= $new_rsa ) {
    &check_for_factor( $p, $q, $z )
      if ( ( length($p) || length($q) ) >=
        ( ( $length_of_semiprime / 2 ) - 1 ) );
}
else {
    last;
}
}

# This sub() is used for the first two calculations
sub first_two_calcs {
my ( $p, $q ) = @_;
my $z = $p * $q;
my $x = $z / 9;

# if its a whole number we move along
if ( ( $z % 9 ) == 0 ) {
    print "($p * $q) / 9 = $x\n";
}
else {
    print "num doesn't div evenly: ($p * $q) / 9 = $x\n";
    $x = int( $x / 10 );
    print "new num: (($p * $q) / 9) / 10 = $x\n";
}
return $x;
}

# /*
#  * This sub() checks to see if it is a factor.
#  *
#  */
sub check_for_factor {
my ( $p, $q, $z ) = @_;

print "Check_for_factor(p = $p, q = $q, z = $z)\n";

for ( $p, $q ) {
    my $temp = $new_rsa - $z;
    my $y    = ( $temp / $_ );

    if ( ( $temp % $_ ) == 0 ) {
        print "\n******* factor found: $_ for $rsa *******\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    elsif ( ( int( $y / 10 ) ) == $new_rsa ) {
        print "\n******* factor found: $_ for $rsa *******\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        print "factor NOT found: ($new_rsa - $z) / $_ = $y\n";
    }
}
}

# This sub() is used for the rest of the calculations
sub second_calcs {
my ( $y, $z ) = @_;
my $j = $z - $y;
my $k = $j + 180;
my $l = $z + $k;

print "$z - $y = |$j|\n";
print "$j + 180 = $k\n";
print "$k + $z = $l\n";

return ( $k, $l );
}

sub third_calc {
my ( $y, $z ) = @_;

my $k = $y + 180;
my $l = $z + $k;

return ( $k, $l );
}

# /*
#  * This sub() calcs the digit root:
#  * example: $rsa = 12345
#  * 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 and 1 + 5 = 6 (digit root)
#  */
sub digit_root {
my $rsa = shift;

$rsa = Math::BigInt->new($rsa);

return ( 1 + ( ( $rsa - 1 ) % 9 ) );
}
```

Comment: `raw_input('copy and paste the above number')` -- wtf?

Comment: @J. W. Helkenburg: I'm willing to help you with an implementation, if you can give me a clear description of the sequence. Trying to interpret your code, or anything named Perl is a waste of my time :) I can be found on #pygrafix at irc.freenode.org.

Comment: You hired a programmer to write THAT mess?

Comment: I allow people to copy and paste the "above number" as an example. You can enter any number you wish, but RSA-100 is my test number (since the factors are already known).

Comment: Yeah, and it (the Perl program) is a mess isn't it! Lame - I would never have selected Perl if I had any foreknowledge of languages. It just happened by accident.

Comment: x_0 and x_1 are not defined before the execution of the "This code will not compile" block.

Comment: Are x_0 and x_1 meant to be exogenous variables?

Comment: @ Joel Cornett: x_0 is the first step of a integer sequence, x_1 is the second step. But in the 24 equations, I need the step value to correspond to the z term. 0 = r - [(((90*n)+11)*y) + z_n]
0 = [(((r-z_n)/y)-11)]/n - 90] So x_0 = the value of z at the zeroth step. I need to solve for y (since x and z are known). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ Joel Cornett: The value of x is simply the value of the step (not an outside value). So x=0 when z is in the first value, x=1 when z is at the second value, etc. I need to solve for y such that r - (equation) = 0.

Comment: @J.W.Helkenberg: we can move this discussion to a more appropriate forum. If you want, you can google chat me at joel.cornett@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue with your code (the part that you label "THIS CODE WILL NOT COMPILE") is that you're using `[`square brackets`]` where you should be using parentheses. In python, unlike in mathematics, the square brackets denote a very specific data type called a list. You should replace your square brackets with regular parentheses.

```
print ((int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0))/90 #example 23 
print ((int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1))/90 #example 215  
z(0) = ((int(p) + 90*x_0) * int(q)+ 90*x_0))/90 
z(1) = ((int(p) + 90*x_1) * (int(q)+90*x_1))/90
```

Also, `z(n)` is going to give you problems. I'm not quite sure what z(0) is supposed to be programmatically. Unless z is a function however, you would probably want `z` to be a list of `n` elements. In which case you would access those elements with `z[1], z[2], ... z[n]`.

That's probably not everything wrong, but it's a start. I recommend reading the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) at python.org, and also looking at examples of python code to improve your understanding.

Comment: The code will not compile because it is pseudo-code and not Python. Here is something another user suggested.                          p = 29
q = 73
g = 180

# prevent re-calculation of previous terms by memoization
z_results = {
    0: int(((p + 90.0 * 0) * (q + 90.0 * 0)) / 90.0),
    1: int(((p + 90.0 * 1) * (q + 90.0 * 1)) / 90.0),
}

def z(x):
    if x in z_results:
        return z_results[x]

    result = g + 2*z(x - 1) - z(x - 2)
    z_results[x] = result
    return result

for i in range(20):
    print("%d: %d" % (i, z(i)))